# SceneKit - Get the rendered scene from a SCNView as a MTLTexture without using a separate SCNRenderer

Tags: ios, scenekit, metal

My **SCNView** is using Metal as the rendering API and I would like to know if there's a way to grab the rendered scene as a **MTLTexture** without having to use a separate **SCNRenderer**? Performance drops when I'm trying to both display the scene via the **SCNView** and re-rendering the scene offscreen to a **MTLTexture** via a **SCNRenderer** (I'm trying to grab the output every frame).

**SCNView** gives me access to the **MTLDevice**, **MTLRenderCommandEncoder**, and **MTLCommandQueue** that it uses, but not to the underlying **MTLRenderPassDescriptor** that I would need in order to get the **MTLTexture** (via `renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].texture`)

Some alternatives I tried was trying to use `SCNView.snapshot()` to get a UIImage and converting it but performance was even worse.

Comment: Based on what it says here https://developer.apple.com/reference/metal/mtlrenderpassattachmentdescriptor you need to create a new MTLRenderPassDescriptor, get the MTLRenderPassAttachmentDescriptor and set a MTLTexture as your render target. Given what you have available, such as the MTLRenderCommandEncoder, it seems like they made that available for you to draw to, not grab the buffer from. If you can create your own MTLRenderPassDescriptor and give that to SCNView you could set the render target.

Comment: Oh it looks like you can set your own MTLRenderPassDescriptor with SCNRenderer https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnrenderer That's probably what you need to do.

Comment: Setting up a SCNRenderer causes it to re-render the scene (since it's on its own render cycle), causing a performance drop. I was hoping to just grab the underlying texture from the already rendered scene (assuming SCNView renders into one, which would seem to be the case since it uses a CAMetalLayer as the backing layer for the view).

Comment: Are you trying to make a mirror?

Comment: I was thinking this would be a really strange mirror that doesn't reflect, nm! I'm curious as to how you solve this problem though.

Comment: I'm basically trying to record the scene into a video file in real-time using AVAssetWriter. I know I could use ReplayKit to do this, but it's unfortunately very limited to what you can do with the recorded video (you can't really set any transcoding settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** Warning: This may not be a proper method for App Store. But it's working.

Step 1: Swap the method of nextDrawable of CAMetalLayer with a new one using swizzling.
Save the CAMetalDrawable for each render loop.

```
extension CAMetalLayer {
  public static func setupSwizzling() {
    struct Static {
      static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
      let copiedOriginalSelector = #selector(CAMetalLayer.orginalNextDrawable)
      let originalSelector = #selector(CAMetalLayer.nextDrawable)
      let swizzledSelector = #selector(CAMetalLayer.newNextDrawable)

      let copiedOriginalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, copiedOriginalSelector)
      let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
      let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

      let oldImp = method_getImplementation(originalMethod)
      method_setImplementation(copiedOriginalMethod, oldImp)
      method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
    }
  }


  func newNextDrawable() -> CAMetalDrawable? {
    let drawable = orginalNextDrawable()
    // Save the drawable to any where you want
    AppManager.sharedInstance.currentSceneDrawable = drawable
    return drawable
  }

  func orginalNextDrawable() -> CAMetalDrawable? {
    // This is just a placeholder. Implementation will be replaced with nextDrawable.
    return nil
  }
}
```

Step 2:
Setup the swizzling in AppDelegate: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
  CAMetalLayer.setupSwizzling()
  return true
}
```

Step 3:
Disable framebufferOnly for your's SCNView's CAMetalLayer (In order to call getBytes for MTLTexture)

```
if let metalLayer = scnView.layer as? CAMetalLayer {
  metalLayer.framebufferOnly = false
}
```

Step 4:
In your SCNView's delegate (SCNSceneRendererDelegate), play with the texture

```
func renderer(renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: NSTimeInterval) {
    if let texture = AppManager.sharedInstance.currentSceneDrawable?.texture where !texture.framebufferOnly {
      AppManager.sharedInstance.currentSceneDrawable = nil
      // Play with the texture
    }
}
```

Step 5 (Optional):
You may need to confirm the drawable at CAMetalLayer you are getting is your target. (If more then one CAMetalLayer at the same time)

Comment: I didn't even think of that! Very clever! Thank you :)

Comment: @KevinBui did you try this on your application? If so, were there any problems with the App Store?

Comment: @halileohalilei I release an App in App Store without any problem in review.
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/facemous/id1213785099?mt=8

Answer (score 2):

**Updated for Swift 4:**

Swift 4 doesn't support dispatch_once(), and @objc added to replacement functions.  Here's the updated swizzle setup.  This is tested working nicely for me.

```
extension CAMetalLayer {

    // Interface so user can grab this drawable at any time
    private struct nextDrawableExtPropertyData {
        static var _currentSceneDrawable : CAMetalDrawable? = nil
    }
    var currentSceneDrawable : CAMetalDrawable? {
        get {
            return nextDrawableExtPropertyData._currentSceneDrawable
        }
    }

    // The rest of this is just swizzling
    private static let doJustOnce : Any? = {
        print ("***** Doing the doJustOnce *****")
        CAMetalLayer.setupSwizzling()

        return nil
    }()

    public static func enableNextDrawableSwizzle() {
        _ = CAMetalLayer.doJustOnce
    }

    public static func setupSwizzling() {
        print ("***** Doing the setupSwizzling *****")

        let copiedOriginalSelector = #selector(CAMetalLayer.originalNextDrawable)
        let originalSelector = #selector(CAMetalLayer.nextDrawable)
        let swizzledSelector = #selector(CAMetalLayer.newNextDrawable)

        let copiedOriginalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, copiedOriginalSelector)
        let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
        let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)

        let oldImp = method_getImplementation(originalMethod!)
        method_setImplementation(copiedOriginalMethod!, oldImp)

        let newImp = method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod!)
        method_setImplementation(originalMethod!, newImp)

    }


    @objc func newNextDrawable() -> CAMetalDrawable? {
        // After swizzling, originalNextDrawable() actually calls the real nextDrawable()
        let drawable = originalNextDrawable()

        // Save the drawable
        nextDrawableExtPropertyData._currentSceneDrawable = drawable

        return drawable
    }

    @objc func originalNextDrawable() -> CAMetalDrawable? {
        // This is just a placeholder. Implementation will be replaced with nextDrawable.
        // ***** This will never be called *****
        return nil
    }
}
```

In your AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Swizzle
    CAMetalLayer.enableNextDrawableSwizzle()

    return true
}
```

Updated to add a **currentSceneDrawable** property to CAMetalLayer, so you can just use **layer.currentSceneDrawable** to access it, rather than having the extension store it externally.